# Dynamic SQL Pivot - removing nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

this is my first attempt at dynamic pivoting in SQL and I have become a bit stuck!

I have two tables that I am joining on, one holds stock items and the other holds different prices for stock items for different websites(sources). As there is the possibility of having different sites, the query needs to be dynamic.

The problem is that I cannot remove nulls from the results and I was hoping that someone could help.

results look like this currently:

```
ID    site-site1   site-site2    site-site3
1      null          1.99          2.99
2      12.99         null          10.00
3      1.50          null          2.00
```

The query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @sources nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sources = 
STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + 
CASE 
WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '' THEN 'Default'
ELSE ip.[Source] 
END 
+ ' - ' +  
CASE 
WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '' THEN  'Default'
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END  
+ ']'
    FROM itemprice ip
    for XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT 
s.id, 
[Source] = CASE 
               WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '''' THEN  ''Default'' 
       ELSE ip.[Source] 
       END + '' - '' +  
CASE WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '''' THEN ''Default''
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END, 
    SalePrice = isnull(ip.SalePrice, 0)  
    FROM stock s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN itemprice ip on ip.id = s.id
) data 
PIVOT 
( 
  MAX(SalePrice) for [Source] IN (' + @sources + ')
) as PivotTable
ORDER BY PivotTable.id'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it appears as though it is not as simple as wrapping each @sources item in an ISNULL.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by remove the nulls? What do you want to take their place?

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear, in this case I needed 0s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to ISNULL each of the individual pivoted columns.  Either that or CROSS JOIN your `data` subquery to generate the full matrix and perform ISNULL there.

e.g. to replace NULLs with 0's using ISNULL on pivoted columns:

```
DECLARE @sources nvarchar(max), @Selectlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sources = 
STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + 
CASE 
WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '' THEN 'Default'
ELSE ip.[Source] 
END 
+ ' - ' +  
CASE 
WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '' THEN  'Default'
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END  
+ ']'
    FROM itemprice ip
    for XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @Selectlist = 
STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL([' + 
CASE 
WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '' THEN 'Default'
ELSE ip.[Source] 
END 
+ ' - ' +  
CASE 
WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '' THEN  'Default'
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END  
+ '],0) [' + 
CASE 
WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '' THEN 'Default'
ELSE ip.[Source] 
END 
+ ' - ' +  
CASE 
WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '' THEN  'Default'
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END  
+ ']'
    FROM itemprice ip
    for XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT ID, ' + @Selectlist + '
FROM 
(
SELECT 
s.id, 
[Source] = CASE 
               WHEN ip.[Source] is null or ip.[Source] = '''' THEN  ''Default'' 
       ELSE ip.[Source] 
       END + '' - '' +  
CASE WHEN ip.secondSource is null or ip.secondSource = '''' THEN ''Default''
ELSE ip.secondSource 
END, 
    SalePrice = isnull(ip.SalePrice, 0)  
    FROM stock s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN itemprice ip on ip.id = s.id
) data 
PIVOT 
( 
  MAX(SalePrice) for [Source] IN (' + @sources + ')
) as PivotTable
ORDER BY PivotTable.id'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: +1, however, it is better to use `QUOTENAME(Column)` rather than `'[' + column + ']'. If one of the dynamically created columns contains `[` or `]`, `QUOTENAME` will escape this and do it's best to ensure the output is a valid column for selecting.

Comment: Although having said that I think that if any of the dynamically created columns contains square brackets it will cause the replace to fail to... Perhaps generating the column lists for the pivot and the select separately would be a more robust solution?

Comment: The pivot column list **IS** the base select column list. And if the solution is working for the OP, I'm not going to bet against the column names not containing `[]`. But yes, I personally use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: But the solution was incorrect (just fixed) - ISNULL would have lost all the column names, so generating the SELECT/PIVOT columns separately seems inescapable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that there may be better ways to do this, however I am just glad to get it complete! Thanks  RichardTheKiwi. 
GarethD I am using SQL on a day to day basis now so your comments are also helpful!